# What is the def to_s function?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm going through the "Tags" section of the [Blogger](http://tutorials.jumpstartlab.com/projects/blogger.html#i3%3a-tagging) tutorial and am a bit confused on one part: the def to_s function (in tag.rb); why it's required and how it's included.

I've included some relevant parts of relevant files for context.

***MODELS***

**article.rb**

```
class Article < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :tag_list
  has_many :taggings
  has_many :tags, through: :taggings

  def tag_list
    return self.tags.collect do |tag|
      tag.name
    end.join(", ")
  end

  def tag_list=(tags_string)
    self.taggings.destroy_all

      tag_names = tags_string.split(",").collect{|s| s.strip.downcase}.uniq

      tag_names.each do |tag_name|
        tag = Tag.find_or_create_by_name(tag_name)
        tagging = self.taggings.new
        tagging.tag_id = tag.id
      end
    end
  end
```

**tag.rb**

```
class Tag < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :taggings
  has_many :articles, through: :taggings

  def to_s
    name
  end
end
```

**tagging.rb**

```
class Tagging < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :tag
  belongs_to :article
end
```

***CONTROLLERS***

**tags_controller.rb**

```
class TagsController < ApplicationController

  def index
    @tags = Tag.all
  end

  def show
    @tag = Tag.find(params[:id])
  end

  def destroy
    @tag = Tag.find(params[:id]).destroy
    redirect_to :back
  end
end
```

***HELPERS***

**articles_helper.rb**

```
module ArticlesHelper

  def tag_links(tags)
    links = tags.collect{|tag| link_to tag.name, tag_path(tag)}
    return links.join(", ").html_safe
  end
end
```

***VIEWS***

**new.html.erb**

```
<%= form_for(@article, html: {multipart: true}) do |f| %>
  <p>
    <%= f.label :tag_list %>
    <%= f.text_field :tag_list %>
  </p>
  <p>
    <%= f.submit %>
  </p>
<% end %>
```

**show.html.erb**

Tags: `<%= tag_links(@article.tags) %>`

Comment: fyi: `def tag_list; self.tags.map(&:name).join(", "); end`

Answer (score 6):

I got your point. When you concatenate value in string you have to write 
eg

```
"hello #{@user.name}"
```

So instead of calling @user.name u can specify whatever u have to display user as a string you can directly specify in to_s method so that you dont need to call .to_s again just write

```
"hello #{@user}"
```

above line of code search for .to_s method for @user's class and print returning value.

same is for routing like

```
user_path(@user)
```

will give you >> ***users/123***  # where 123 is id of @user

if you write

```
def to_params
 self.name
end
```

Then it will give >> ***users/john*** # where john is the @user's name

Answer (score 2):

`to_s` is the standard Ruby method for converting an Object into a string. You define `to_s` when you want a custom string representation for your class. Example:

```
1.to_s #=> "1"
StandardError.new("ERROR!").to_s #=> "ERROR!"
```

And so on.

Comment: Thanks.  I guess my real question is how in the heck does Rails know to call that function and what does the function call it on?

Comment: @dresdin ruby is duck typing. Rails does know if it should call or not, but it just calls. If no respond, an error will raise. to_s is pretty standard name for converting an object to string. Every object has it.

Comment: @dresdin: Every object has it because it is defined in `Object`. So you can assume that all objects have `to_s`, and as such, just call it without worrying about whether an object defines it.

Comment: @Linuxios: That's the weird part.  `to_s` isn't being called anywhere.  It's just defined in `tag.rb`.  It's also strange because I thought something as basic as `to_s` would already exist in Ruby/Rails.

Answer (score 1):

`to_s` is a function that returns the string equivalent of the object.

In this case, you have `Tag.to_s` defined, which allows you to do something like this

```
tag = Tag.new(:name => "SomeTag")
tag.to_s #=> "SomeTag"
```

You can add more logic to `to_s` to have a more friendly string, rather than an object hashcode when you want string from a tag (ex. while printing to console).