# Access target object with Hash

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, hash

I have a hash as below. I need to know whether I can access the `display_name` object so it returns the Active Record values.

```
{ "actor"=> 
  { "id"=>1, "class"=>"User", "display_name"=>"#<User:0x007ffc8c498b18>" } 
}
```

I'm assuming I can, as they wouldn't have added it in the first place. I know I can use the id and class keys, but there must be a reason to have the target object. If this isn't possible, why do you think they added it, and what can I do with it?

Comment: "I'm assuming I can" No, you definitely can't. It's useless. We can't possibly guess why "they" added it, we can only assume they added it in error. Does that look like a "display name" to you?

Comment: If that's actually the structure you have, it looks like there's a bug somewhere, as that looks like the result of Object#inspect rather than the object itself has been set as the value in the hash.

Comment: @meagar WOW...don't know if it's the way I've read your message but please don't be rude. I'm asking the question because I don't know and thats why I come on SO to find out. @Chuck Thanks, I'll have a look into the code and see if the `Object#Inspect` is being used here.

Comment: Could be a fallback value (`User#to_s`) for an actual "display name" the class is supposed to provide.

Comment: This is what the code is doing `display_name: target.to_s`. @Stefan I think you could be right with the fallback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, you can't do this with the existing hash. The value associated with the "display_name" key is a string. This means you won't be able to get to all the user methods and attributes. If I had to guess, I'd say that the person who wrote the code that generates the hash may have assumed the User class had a `to_s` method on it that would return the display name.

**I'd try one of these approaches:**

1. Add a `to_s` method to `User` that will return the name you need. This might store the appropriate data in your hash.
2. Look up the user you need by using the "id" key, and then call the attributes you need.
3. Modify the code that creates the hash, so that you store the actual `User` instance, rather than a string representation of it.
4. Modify the code that creates the hash, and store the appropriate attribute of the user, rather than the string representation of it.

It sounds like you want to do option 3 above. If you do, I'd suggest renaming the "display_name" key to "user" to make it a bit more clear what you're storing.

Comment: I ended up doing option 1 after finding this post, which helped to explain what was going on: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15513154/what-is-the-def-to-s-function. I'll accept your answer though as you've explained a number of different solutions.